# Getting "end of record reached while expected to parse column" error while trying load csv file to snowflake db

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to load csv file to snowflake which has the below data.
But i am getting "end of record reached while expected to parse column" error.
   customer_key,product,customer_id,first_name,last_name,res_version,updated_at
1234,desk,10977,Harry,Western \,1,20-04-1994

I have put the code i tried below. Can someone help me solve this error.

```
cs.execute("PUT file://"+cleaned_path+"file_name.csv @%file_name")
cs.execute("""copy into file_namefile_format=(type=csv skip_header=1  FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '"' EMPTY_FIELD_AS_NULL = TRUE)""")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try one of these options:

ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD = None

or something like this:
COPY INTO table
FROM ( select replace(t.$1,'\') from @table/test.txt.gz t)
FILE_FORMAT=(TYPE=CSV FIELD_DELIMITER='\x01')